# React page not rendering when using Okta

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, okta

I working on React app which is secured by Okta OAuth provider. Currently, all of my routes are authenticated. I want a public route where anyone can access it. Eg: https://my.example.com/welcome

These are the configs that I have used

application.yml

```
okta:
  oauth2:
    issuer: https://xxxxxxxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default
    clientId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    clientSecret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    post-logout-redirect-uri: /
    redirect-uri: /login/callback
```

Spring security config

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",  "/welcome").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .and().oauth2Client()
                    .and().oauth2Login();
                    return httpSecurity.build();
```

React Route

```
<Route path={"/welcome"} exact={true} render={(props) => (<WelcomePage/>)}/>
```

When I visit /welcome route I'm getting a blank page with this warning message in the browser

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://xxxxxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxx&scope=profile%20email%20openid&state=rDYLqV7WDv2la1onSvQsTNeXCvDmWhS0_ZoPFlMAE80%3D&redirect_uri=https://xxxxxx.xxxxx.com/careportal/login/callback&nonce=XvMoC5iP5OGYsvG0bS-QfQh1yfYmhNohmD7GvfukyCo with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Can anyone help me to access a public route without auth?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you have anything else than `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` as OAuth2 lib in your Spring project, remove it and [configure your Spring REST API as a resource-server](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

With the helper lib from second tutorial, this might be enough:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <!-- replace "webmvc" with "weblux" for reactive app -->
    <!-- replace "jwt" with "introspecting" if Okta access-tokens are not JWTs -->
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity // replace with @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity for reactive app
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
}
```

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://xxxxxxxxx.okta.com/
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=groups
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.permit-all=/,/welcome
# following might be too permissive, restrict if needed
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/**
```

With Spring `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` only, there is quite some more Java conf to write (refer to first tutorial)

Do not forget to request `groups` (and maybe `openid` and `offline_access`) scopes when you authenticate users from your React app or other clients like Postman.

Comment: Just curious, this wasn't of any help?